# Sort and select lines with the maximum value

Tags: shell, unix

I have a directory with files matching name pattern `A-B.diff`, where `A` and `B` are numbers, e.g.:

```
100885-40843.diff
100885-41535.diff
100886-40500.diff
101036-41762.diff
101036-42346.diff
101038-42010.diff
101038-42127.diff
101038-43258.diff
101038-43873.diff
```

I would like to get a list of these files matching below criteria:

- for every `A` there is only one file
- `B` has the maximum value available for the given `A`

So for the given files the list should be:

```
100885-41535.diff
100886-40500.diff
101036-42346.diff
101038-43873.diff
```

Comment: Use `sort` to sort the list, and `awk` to select one line per A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store data in a file, this makes it:

```
$ awk -F"[-.]" '{if ($2 > a[$1]) a[$1]=$2} END{for (i in a) printf "%s-%s.diff\n",i, a[i]}' file
100885-41535.diff
100886-40500.diff
101036-42346.diff
101038-43873.diff
```

Loops through the list of files creating an array with `a[1st part] = biggest 2nd part`.

Comment: Awesome! Brilliant solution. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

One way using `sort` and `uniq` is

```
sort -t- -r -k2 | sort -t- -rs | uniq -w6
```

`-t-` sets the separator to be the minus sign, `-k2` selects the second column to be sorted, `-r` sorts from greatest to least, and `-s` forces the sort to be stable. Then, `uniq -w6` is the same as `uniq` (select unique lines from a sorted list) except that it only checks the first six characters. Once you execute this command, the lines are sorted by `A` and by `B`, and for each `A` its first occurrence has the maximal `B`, so `uniq` selects that line. On your input, this displays the output

```
101038-43873.diff
101036-42346.diff
100886-40500.diff
100885-41535.diff
```

I suppose if you want the list in its natural order you can append another `sort -n` (sort by number).

Comment: +1. Note that you can further reduce this to `sort -k1,1n -k2,2nr -t- | uniq -w6`